# Eclipse Luna: Built in browser won't redirect from .jsp

Tags: java, html, eclipse, jsp

The code I'm using is in HTML:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;Page.jsp">
```

I'm running this on a different PC than I developed it on, and as far as I'm aware the entire server/website project works when exported as a .war file from either PC, but it just doesn't work in Eclipse's built in browser. Any ideas on what the problem is?

Comment: The syntax should be: `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3; URL=Page.jsp">`

Comment: Well the thing is the .war compiled from any computer works. And it works on several other PCs, all except my personal laptop's eclipse.

Comment: Some browsers may have quirks to cover popular mistakes that Eclipse didn't bother to code for.

Comment: The internal browser in Eclipse is just Mozilla / Webkit / Internet Explorer depending on the platform.

Comment: What happens instead of showing the rendered JSP? What happens if you open the same URL outside of Eclipse?

Comment: Ah, I see @greg-449. That's what it is. How can I change it?  The html redirect is on a JSP page. The JSP page that has the redirect code loads but it never redirects to its target.